# Round corners for autosizing UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, autosize

Is it possible to make rounded corners (**topLeft and topRight**) to autosizing uiview?
Here is my code:

*SFDetailViewController.h*

```
@interface SFDetailViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, PopoverViewListDelegate>
{
  ...

  UIView *header;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *header;

@end
```

*SFDetailViewController.m*

```
#import "SFDetailViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface SFDetailViewController ()
@end


@implementation SFDetailViewController
@syntesyze header;

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    ....
    [self setCornerRadiusToHeader:header];
 }



-(void) setCornerRadiusToHeader:(UIView *)headerView
{    
    CGRect bounds = headerView.layer.bounds;
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bounds 
                                               byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                                     cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(8.0, 8.0)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

    [headerView.layer addSublayer:maskLayer];
    headerView.layer.mask = maskLayer; 

}
```

The view is defined in IB as:

[image: IB]

What I get - the topRight corner is straight, because the size of the view is dynamic.

[image: result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your `UIView`'s `contentMode` property to something like `UIViewContentModeRedrew`. The content mode controls how the view's content changes when its bounds are changed (like when it is autoresized). By default, it just stretches the view's contents, which is why your corners get stretched.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

Thanks to jbrennan, i set

```
header.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
```

Then, in viewDidLoad i call:

```
[header setNeedsDisplay];
```

Which, by the way, calls:  `(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` that i wrote the following:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{ 
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(context, rect); 

    UIColor *color = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);

    CGRect rrect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect)-2, CGRectGetMinY(rect), CGRectGetWidth(rect)+4, CGRectGetHeight(rect) + 1);
    CGFloat radius = 10.0f;

    CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX(rrect), midx = CGRectGetMidX(rrect), maxx = CGRectGetMaxX(rrect);
    CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY(rrect), midy = CGRectGetMidY(rrect), maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(rrect);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, minx, midy);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minx, miny, midx, miny, radius);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxx, miny, maxx, midy, radius);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxx, maxy, midx, maxy, 0);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minx, maxy, minx, midy, 0);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);

}
```

RESULT:

[image: result]